# Must I enter the Schengen area using the E-gates?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, biometric-passports

Must I enter the Schengen  area using the E-gates if you have an EU biometric passport?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is discouraged to avoid them if you are eligible, but there is nothing in the [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407) that mentions automated passport control one way or the other.  Practice may vary from one country to another, since electronic gates are implemented by each country rather than by a central authority.

Last summer, I was leaving the Schengen area via Amsterdam Schiphol with someone who had a non-biometric EU passport.  We went to the desk, but approached separately.  As the officer handed my passport back to me, he asked if I was traveling alone.  I said "no" and that was the end of it.  I suspect that if I had said "yes" he would have suggested that I use the gates the next time.  But since this happened *after* he processed me, he obviously wasn't going to send me to the gates because I lacked an adequate reason not to use them.

To echo Mark Mayo's answer, here's a quote from [Schiphol's website](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/page/passports-and-travel-documents/), with emphasis added:

> Cross the border faster with eGate
>
> eGate is an automatic self-service border checkpoint. You cross the border faster than with a manual inspection because you scan your own passport. You **can** use the automatic gates if you are 16 or over and hold an EU passport that contains a microchip. Follow the instructions at the gate for a smooth passage. Watch the video below to see how the system works.

Similarly, from [the German federal police](https://www.easypass.de/EasyPass/EN/What_is_EasyPASS/_functions/Video/easypass_imagefilm.html;jsessionid=8CB651EE7A769954BEE241D0878E7A95.1_cid289) (I found this link on a page from [Frankfurt airport](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/travel/transfer.detail.suffix.html/article/travel/checks/easypass.html)):

> What is EasyPASS?
>
> ...
>
> This free of charge and **voluntary** service is an important component of integrated border management in Europe. The EU supports the new control system with funds from the European External Borders Fund.

Comment: (+1) Also, eligibility also depend on the country and specific equipment used. Sometimes automatic passport gates are not open to all EU citizens, sometimes they are open to select third countries as well.